# Python - modifying CSV Files from file path in text file

Tags: python, csv, copy, pydev

I am trying to write a simple python program (in Eclipse Juno using Pydev) to load multiple .CSV files to be copied and re-outputted via CSV. (eventually the "copy" feature will be replaced with selecting certain columns then re-outputting the csv file)

So far I have got the program to upload a single CSV file and output it where the user specifies via a save dialog box (just copies the file for now).

A dialog box pops up and asks to select files (multiple selection works) but i am not sure on how to interpret/parse and save the multiple csv input files statically to an assigned location on my computer (C:/).

Here's a simple run down of the program task:

input CSV files -> copy -> output CSV files to static location on computer

I will include my code in this post,

Any help is greatly appreciated!! :-)

### CODE:

**FILE UPLOAD**

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames

Tk().withdraw() 
filenames = askopenfilenames() 
print(filenames)
```

**FILE COPY/MANIPULATION**

```
import csv
import tkFileDialog

ifile = open(filenames)
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
```

**SAVE AS DIALOG BOX**

```
ofile = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
print filenames 

writer = csv.writer(open(ofile, 'wb'))

for row in reader:
writer.writerow(row)
```

**STATUS DIALOG BOX**

```
import tkMessageBox
tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Conversion Successful", message="CSV File has been successfully converted")
```

Comment: Do you want to copy all the files to a single location, or do you want to have a dialog box pop up for each selected file?

Comment: Seems like you probably need to iterate over the filenames and do something for each...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, you might try something like this:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames  
Tk().withdraw() 

filenames = askopenfilenames() 

# askopenfilenames() returns a list of filenames. Loop through them one at a time
for fin in filenames:
  ifile = open(fin)
  reader = csv.reader(ifile)

  # For each file, ask where to save it, then write it out.
  ofile = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
  writer = csv.writer(open(ofile, 'wb'))
  for row in reader:
    # Whatever you modify probably goes here.
    writer.writerow(row)

    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Conversion Successful", message="CSV File '{0}' has been successfully converted and was written to '{1}'".format(fin,ofile)

  ifile.close()
```

Comment: Id like to copy all files that are selected into a single location in the C:/temp folder. I'm not sure how to parse the multiple selection from the input dialog box.

Comment: As I explained, `askopenfilenames()` appears to return a list of file names. You can iterate over those filenames as shown in my example `for fin in filenames:`. In each iteration, `fin` will contain one of the filenames.